# How to select floating point data from json array in postgreSQL

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jsonb

I have postgreSQL table 'prices' that contains column 'json_column',
this column contains json array as given:

```json
[
    {
        "price": 10.10,
        "createdBy": "test_user"
    },
    {
        "price": 14.99,
        "createdBy": "test_user"
    },
    {
        "price": 20.10,
        "createdBy": "test_user"
    }
]
```

I want to select all prices from that array that is grater than 15.0.

I did have few attempts like so:

```sql
select json_column->'price' as price_values
from prices
where json_column->'price'::numeric < 20.0;
```

but nothing seems to work for me, can I get any help with this as might seem simple query?:)

[EDIT]
I did try this valid query as was suggested, but the response is empty, even without the WHERE part:

```sql
select json_column->>'price' as price_values
from prices
where (json_column->>'price')::numeric < 20.0;
```

The result I expect is something like this:

```
| price_values |
|--------------|
| 10.10        |
| 14.99        |
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your array is on one row like mine:

```
 id |           json_column
----+----------------------------------
  1 | [                               +
    |     {                           +
    |         "price": 10.10,         +
    |         "createdBy": "test_user"+
    |     },                          +
    |     {                           +
    |         "price": 14.99,         +
    |         "createdBy": "test_user"+
    |     },                          +
    |     {                           +
    |         "price": 20.10,         +
    |         "createdBy": "test_user"+
    |     }                           +
    | ]
```

That decision will be as follows: we make a subquery in which we use `'json_array_elements'`. Select data from the subquery into the price_values column, where using `WHERE` we select the desired values.

```
SELECT price_values
FROM(SELECT (json_array_elements(json_column)->'price') AS price_values
FROM prices) AS foo
WHERE price_values::text::numeric < 20.0
;
```

Output:

```
 price_values
--------------
 10.10
 14.99
```